# Algorithmic efficiency in selecting based on bits

Tags: c, logic, bit-shift, bit

I was wondering what your ideas were in developing an efficient algorithm for doing if/else switch/cases based on bits. I have 8 bits to play with and I need to divide them into higher order and lower order bits, like so:

`0000 1111`

Each half contains some information base on which bits are turned on. For example, if the lower half (`1111` in this little endian machine) is actually `0010`, something happens. Furthermore, if the higher end is `1000`, something else happens.

I guess it would be efficient to rightshift the upper half and make `AND` comparisons (like `(x >> 4) & 8)` but I'm not sure what's smart to do for the lower half, as it seems a bit unclever to left shift and compare to some weird number.

Your insights, again, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `(x >> 4) & 8` in your example isn't quite right. To compare the higher nibble (the top four bits) to `n`, you need `((x >> 4) & 15) == n`.

To compare the lower nibble to `n`, you simply lose the right shift: `(x & 15) == n`.

Comment: Use `(x & 15) == n`, because `x & 15 == n` is the same as `x & (15 == n)`.  This is a historical accident -- the `&` and `|` operators were used like `&&` and `||` in ancient history, and the precedence rules stuck.

Answer (score 1):

To mask the lower 4 bits you can use `bits & 0xf` and if you want to check whether the 4 bits have a certain value (i.e. 2 which is 0010) you can use `( bits & 0xf ) == 2` for the lower half and `( bits >> 4 ) == 2` for the upper half.

Endianess makes no difference when you are looking at just a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell whether you want something efficient, as you say, or something clever. If you really want fast execution, nothing is faster than a switch statement with 256 cases. Take a look at the code the compiler produces for switch and you'll see that it's very fast.

If you want something clever, that's a different deal. But, no matter how clever it is, it's never going to be faster than a switch.

Comment: That's interesting. Is it because pretty much everything gets distilled down to a switch statement?

Comment: @Rio - No it more like some of the guys writing the compiler are PhD's with 20 years of experience tuning optimizations. Why do you think we could beat that easily?

Comment: Well, a switch is not necessarily the fastest way to do things on modern CPUs, especially not a rather big one with 256 cases. A switch causes branching and pipelining CPUs hate that if they can't predict the right branch and large switch tables mean lots of code which is bad for the instruction cache. Sometimes it's possible to avoid branching entirely with clever bit manipulation and often it's faster to use lookup tables instead of switches if that is possible. You can read more about this topic in these great manuals: http://www.agner.org/optimize/